# Remove a component from an issue in Jira

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, scriptrunner-for-jira

I would like to write code in order to remove a component from an issue. For example, there is a component called WF-EDA and I would like to write code in order to delete it. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(newIssueCreatedID, myissueID, issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
                    Collection<ProjectComponent>  componentList2=issue.getComponents()
                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA COMPONENT LIST 2 "+ componentList2)

                    componentList2.removeAll(issue.getComponents())
                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA COMPONENT LIST 2 "+ componentList2)
                    projectComponentManager.updateIssueProjectComponents( issue, componentList2)
```